# Python timezone processing

Tags: python

Given:
date as a string '2022-12-28T20:55:45Z'

Z in the end indicates the UTC as I understand.
The VM tz is Europe/Paris.

```
import datetime as dt
print(dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%s'))
1672257345
```

Which is December 28, 2022 7:55:45 PM UTC
So this is a hour behind the actual string date.

Explicitly defining the offset doesn't change anything.

```
    print(dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%s'))
    1672257345
    print(dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45+1200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z').strftime('%s'))
    1672257345
```

I don't understand how this is possible.
20:55:45+1200 shall be equal to 08:55:45+0000 but python returns me the same epoch.

Tried pytz with the same result

```
    import pytz
    cet = timezone('CET')
    k = timezone('Europe/Kiev')
    a=dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    cet.localize(a).strftime('%s')
   '1672257345'
   k.localize(a).strftime('%s')
   '1672257345'
```

Comment: `strptime` doesn't understand time zones, I think you'll find the `datetime` objects it returns are always naive.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sure it does, but `.strftime('%s')` isn't valid.  `.timestamp()` returns different timestamps for the different timezones, however.

Comment: @MarkTolonen evidently I was remembering an older version of Python where `%z` wasn't even a valid parameter for `strptime`.  The introduction of `datetime.timezone` in Python 3.2 must have allowed them to fix that oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where `.strftime('%s')` is coming from.  `%s` isn't a valid [format code](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and gives `ValueError: Invalid format string`, but `.timestamp()` gives different numbers for the different time zones:

```py
import datetime as dt
a = dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(a, a.timestamp())
b = dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45+0000', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(b, b.timestamp())
c = dt.datetime.strptime('2022-12-28T20:55:45+1200', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
print(c, c.timestamp())
print((b.timestamp() - c.timestamp()) / 3600)
```

Output:

```
2022-12-28 20:55:45+00:00 1672260945.0
2022-12-28 20:55:45+00:00 1672260945.0
2022-12-28 20:55:45+12:00 1672217745.0
12.0
```

(12-hour difference as expected)

Comment: Since `strptime` and `strftime` rely on underlying C functions, it's possible that `%s` is implemented as a non-standard extension on certain platforms.